# Difference of async lambda and simple lambda in Polly

Tags: c#, asynchronous, lambda, task, polly

```
var retry1 = Policy.Handle<Exception>().RetryAsync(onRetryAsync: (exception, i) => OnRetryAsync());
var retry2 = Policy.Handle<Exception>().RetryAsync(onRetryAsync: async (exception, i) => await OnRetryAsync());



async Task OnRetryAsync()
{
    //My Async Code
}
```

I can't find any information on what's the difference between using `retry1` and `retry2`. As I remember Polly 7 documentation it always use the second variant, why? `retry1` seems more readable in my opinion.